# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string on Array

Tags: php

I am trying to show reviews for a car. I am trying to loop through the arrays of reviews and get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string** error message.

When I do the `var_dump($reviews);` it shows

```php
array(2) {
    ["review"] => string(9) "Great Car"
    [0] => string(9) "Great Car"
}
```

But once I try to put that in a loop I get the error above, with all my CSS disappearing.

```php
$reviews = getReviewByCar($pdo, $_GET['vId']);
```

```
<div class="review-text">
    <?php foreach ((array) $reviews as $review) : ?>
        <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($review['review'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

My database for the getReviewByCar:

```php
function getReviewByCar($pdo, $id) {
    $parameters = [':id' => $id];
    $query = query($pdo, 'SELECT review FROM car_review
    INNER JOIN vehicle ON car_review.vehicle_id = vehicle.vId
    WHERE vehicle_id = :id', $parameters);
    return $query->fetch();
}
```

Comment: That's not how you iterate over an associative array. Give https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php a (re)read. Also, don't cast your array to an array. It's already an array.

Comment: You are also joining to your `vehicle` table but not using any columns from that table. Maybe you want to `return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`?

Comment: Thank you both for the tips, the above code has fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

`query` returns an array of arrays.

From that, `fetch` returns the first row as an array.

From that array, you need to either look at the first column or the column with key `"review"`.

That is, change

```
return $query->fetch();
```

to (as one approach):

```
return $query->fetch()[0];
```